# How can I sniff http traffic between processes on a single host?

Tags: rest, http

I am trying to capture http packets between a Python program and a REST Server on the same machine. I don't know if this traffic is being routed out the network interface where Wireshark can see it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try at least?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to look at *packets*, then you may want to review the information available on [loopback capture](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback).

On the other hand, if your real interest is in the HTTP messages themselves, then you might look into whether or not you can configure your http clients to point at a logging proxy, for example [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Comment: Thank you voice... Indeed, I'm more interested in the http messages... (just easier to guarantee the message is "on the wire", if you get it from the envelopes in an ethernet packet). I've heard of Charles, I'll look into it. Incidentally, I found that Fiddler works as well, I'm guessing in much the same way being a proxy-based tool.